# powershell regex select string in variable

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

I am trying to create a script that select the four numbers that the company computer have in the host name.

I have tested the regex `'\d{4}'` in a regex web site, and it works fine to select the four numbers. but when using it with powershell y only get the $true or $false.

I need that the 4 numbers are keept in a variable for later use but i havent achieved it.

any ideas??

```
$machinename = "mac0016w701"
$test = $machinename -match '\d{4}'

$test2= Select-String -Pattern '\d{4}' -inputobject $machinename
$test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-match` is an operator which returns true/false, so you can use it in tests. If you want the values from the regex, it sets the magic variable `$Matches`, e.g.

```
PS D:\> 'computer1234' -match '\d{4}'
True
PS D:\> $matches[0]
1234
```

Alternately, you could use:

```
[regex]::Matches('computer1234', '\d{4}').Value
```